# Paypal Express Checkout - multiple price options to choose from during payment on Paypal page?

Tags: paypal

I am wondering if there is such thing :
when a vistor clicks "Pay" button (placed on my site)  - **on Paypal site** during payment there will be several options to choose from. Something like three radio buttons

- Pay for one month
- Pay for three months
- Pay for one year

so in order to pay a user should first select which option to pay first.
Again - I just would like to know if such posisbility exists. I know how to set this up on my own site.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wouldn't happen on the PayPal site, but you can certainly get that done on your own site/application.  Build in the logic and interface for them to choose what they want to pay and what schedule to do it on, and then you can use the corresponding PayPal API to get it done.  Specifically, I would recommend the Express Checkout API.

Comment: ys yes I know how to do taht on my own site for sure. jsut though there could be an easy way to feed , say, three options ($10, $20, $666) to Paypal so users can choose and pay on PP site. Googled for a while with no luck.

Comment: You could try a basic Buy Now button with options that adjust the pricing.

Comment: Looks like this is the only solution (even though it is not 100% what I need). Thank you, Andrew